# Simple AJAX/PHP problem but with long explanation

Tags: php, ajax

I just started this book - "AJAX and PHP Second edition" and I failed on the very first example.I'm pretty sure the code is just as it is shown in the book, but still when I run index.htm in the error console(Mozzila 6.0) I get this : "xmlResponse is NULL http://localhost/ajax/quickstart/quickstart.js.I don't know what's going on but really don't want to give up at the very begining so I'll pase all the 3 files and hopefully anyone would point me where the problem is.
Here is the index.htm :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>AJAX with PHP, 2nd Edition: Quickstart</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="quickstart.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="process();">
Server wants to know your name:
<input type="text" id="myName" />
<div id="divMessage" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the quickstart.js :

```
// stores the reference to the XMLHttpRequest object
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();
// retrieves the XMLHttpRequest object
function createXmlHttpRequestObject()
{
// stores the reference to the XMLHttpRequest object
var xmlHttp;
// if running Internet Explorer 6 or older
if(window.ActiveXObject)
{
try {
xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
catch (e) {
xmlHttp = false;
}
}
// if running Mozilla or other browsers
else
{
try {
xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
catch (e) {
xmlHttp = false;
}
}
// return the created object or display an error message
if (!xmlHttp)
alert("Error creating the XMLHttpRequest object.");
else
return xmlHttp;
}
// make asynchronous HTTP request using the XMLHttpRequest object
function process(name)
{
// proceed only if the xmlHttp object isn't busy
if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState == 0)
{
// retrieve the name typed by the user on the form
name = encodeURIComponent(
document.getElementById("myName").value);
// execute the quickstart.php page from the server
xmlHttp.open("GET", "quickstart.php?name=" + name, true);
// define the method to handle server responses
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
// make the server request
xmlHttp.send();
}
else
// if the connection is busy, try again after one second
setTimeout('process()', 1000);
}
// callback function executed when a message is received from the
//server
function handleServerResponse()
{
// move forward only if the transaction has completed
if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
{
// status of 200 indicates the transaction completed
//successfully
if (xmlHttp.status == 200)
{
// extract the XML retrieved from the server
xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
// obtain the document element (the root element) of the XML
//structure
xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
// get the text message, which is in the first child of
// the the document element
helloMessage = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
// display the data received from the server
document.getElementById("divMessage").innerHTML =
'<i>' + helloMessage
+ '</i>';
// restart sequence
setTimeout('process()', 1000);
}
// a HTTP status different than 200 signals an error
else
{
alert("There was a problem accessing the server: " +
xmlHttp.statusText);
        }
    }
}
```

and finally the quickstart.php :

```
<?php
// we'll generate XML output
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
// generate XML header
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>';
// create the <response> element
echo '<response>';
// retrieve the user name
$name = $_GET['name'];
// generate output depending on the user name received from client
$userNames = array('YODA', 'AUDRA', 'BOGDAN', 'CRISTIAN');
if (in_array(strtoupper($name), $userNames))
echo 'Hello, master ' . htmlentities($name) . '!';
else if (trim($name) == '')
echo 'Stranger, please tell me your name!';
else
echo htmlentities($name) . ', I don\'t know you!';
// close the <response> element
echo '</response>';
?>
```

Thanks in advanced!
Leron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems I found with your code. Mentioning some of them

- You are calling the `process()` on body-onload. This means, when the DOM is ready, the browser calls the `process()` function. This, IMO, is not something you would want. Instead, have a button, which calls this process function with the `onclick` event. Something like:

  ```
  <button onclick="process('YODA');return false;">Click Me!</button>
  ```
- Process is defined as taking one parameter called `name`, you are passing none. So, make a fix something like this:

  ```
  <button onclick="myProcess();return false;">Click Me!</button>
  ```

And is your JS section/file

```
function myProcess(){
    process(encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('myName').value));
}
```

- Do not have that `document.getElementById(..)` inside the process function. It defeats the entire purpose of passing that parameter 'name'

I would ask you  to use a really good browser like Mozilla Firefox, or Google Chrome (since you seem to give IE6 a prefence in your code, atleast seems like it!). Chrome has a fantastic inspector window. Once you get the hang of it, you will almost fall in love with it. I did! ;-)

I would suggest, you use libraries like jQuery(www.jquery.com) or something, for ajax. Makes your life easier! :-)

**EDIT**

I would suggest the following steps, since you want to get *this* piece of code working.

- First open the url `[BASE-URL]/quickstate.php?name=YODA`. If everything is just fine, you should see the XML that should be the response to your AJAX call. If not, there's some problem with the PHP file(or a few settings of your server), and not anything else. I feel this step wouldn't be a problem.
- Next, once the page is loaded, type 'YODA' in the textbox, type this in the browser's URL box: `javascript:process('')`. This should call the function that has the ajax call. You could keep a tab on the data transferred section of the firebug(I dont know the name exactly, but its the 'Network' section in Google Chrome). You could analyse the headers sent to the PHP scripts, and the response (including the HTTP error codes) sent back to you from the server. I also feel this wont be a problem.

What causes the problem is: The DOM of the page is loaded. The AJAX call is made once the DOM is ready. This means the AJAX request is made even before you type anything in that textbox. And thus, the request that goes to the server has a empty value for `name` parameter. This is exactly, (IMO) the reason why things are not working for you. But even then, this is not the reason why you see a `null` for XML out there. Could you do a `console.log(xmlHttp)` and tell us the results?

Comment: All true, but he's just trying to get the example from his book to run. First things's first, let him get set up running the examples so he can learn all that. At least he's using Firefox.

Comment: As Nicholas said by now I'm just trying to get the example working.And because it's from the book I guess it should work, also I didn't write it on my own but copy-paste it, so the chance for mistake is even smaller.I thought that maybe some of the code is outdated or something like that because the edition is from 2009 but despite that I really want to make THIS code working and find out where the problem is before going any further.

Comment: http://localhost/ajax/quickstart/quickstart.php?name=YODA I get : 
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\Program Files\webPHP\xampp\htdocs\ajax\quickstart\quickstart.php:1) in C:\Program Files\webPHP\xampp\htdocs\ajax\quickstart\quickstart.php on line 3
Hello, master YODA!

Comment: `<?php` should be the first 5 characters in your PHP file. Not even whitespace should be there. That is why that warning, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

That all looks correct. Where are hosting the PHP script? On a local installation of Apache, or a server you have access to? In Firefox, you can install the incredible Firebug add-on, go to the scripts tab, and see exactly what the request is returning. Whatever it is, Fx isn't recognising it as XML (hence the xmlResponse member being NULL).

Comment: I'm using XAMPP so - yeah, local Apache server.I'll try firebug, but since it's the very first example I just want to make it work and go ahead with the book for now.

Comment: Can you confirm the server is running correctly? What happens when you try to view the page over the local network connection (http://localhost) and also the quickstart script is being correctly run as PHP (http://localhost...path.../quickstart.php). It would be good to see that everything is being returned correctly by the server, then debug the JS.

Comment: The HTML and PHP files are pretty straight forwards so I'm pretty sure they are fine.The index file works fine for sure, I'll try the PHP too, but as I point at the beginning the erroe is xmlResponse NULL so I guess it's .js afterall

Comment: Well, the response might be NULL because the server's serving things incorrectly. Tell us also, please, what the network tab in Firebug is telling you. It will list all the requests, and you can inspect the content of each.

Comment: I currently don't have firebug installed, gonna proceed with the problem later.Obviously it won't be as easy as I thought and I feel a bit tired right now, thanks for the help.